# Will git pull command overwrite non-commit changes

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-pull

Git `pull` command will `fetch` + `merge` remote branch to local branch . And if there are merge conflict between commits , you can resolves it locally  .

But what if I never `commit` anything I changed locally and `pull` a remote updated branch ?

Will git ignores my local non-commit changes and straight off overwrite my local branch ?

Does this mean I should always `commit` before pulling to update local branch ?

Comment: You mention, later (in a comment), using VSCode. If you're clicking various buttons in VSCode, be aware that this doesn't necessarily do the same thing Git would do. (I don't use VSCode so I can't say for sure what it does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have local changes when you run `git pull` then the the command will just fail if it would overwrite your local changes (with an error message that tells you that is why it failed).

If you want to pull without losing local changes you can include `--autostash` in your pull command, then git will stash your local changes, run the pull, and then restore your changes from the stash.

Comment: I try it myself in visual studio code windows command prompt. I don't see the error message after pull . It however gives me the up to date message while nothing changed locally in my branch . Is that normal ?

Comment: update : There are error message actually , Something like this 
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: `git pull` *will* allow the pull if (1) you're using a rebase as the second command *and* (2) you have turned on "autostash" for rebasing. We don't know if @AkiZukiLenn is doing (1) nor whether he has enabled (2). (We might *assume* a "no" on item 1 due to the mention of `pull`=`fetch`+`merge`, but the error message seen suggests that perhaps this *was* a stash pop merge that failed here.)

Answer (score 1):

If you run `git pull` with local changes :

- the `git fetch` part is not impacted by your changes, it may fail for known reasons (network error, invalid credentials ...)
  if it succeeds, your remote branches will be updated, and `git pull` will proceed to the next step
- the `git merge` part will try to combine your local changes with the result of the merge, just like a regular `git merge origin/mybranch` would do

`git merge` has a number of safety mechanism to avoid deleting your local work.

For example, if file `foo.txt` needs merging and you have local changes on it, `git` will abort the merge and display the following message :

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    foo.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

If your local changes are "compatible" with proceeding with the merge (e.g: are on files which are not modified by the merge operation), `git` will proceed with the merge.

---

`git pull` (and `git merge`) have a `--autostash` option, which will make `git` automatically run `git stash` before the operation, and `git stash pop` after it if the operation is successful.

That way `git` will always proceed with the merge. Be aware, however, that you may have to resolve conflicts at two different steps: once for the merge, and one second time for the `stash pop` operation.

---

The `merge` operation may be a `pull` operation (if you run `git rebase --pull`, or if you turn `git config pull.reabse true` for example) ; in that case, `git` flat out refuses to proceed with the rebase if there are any uncommitted modifications.

Again, you can use `autostash`.